# Return to the section of the page after using get method instead of the start of the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

I am trying to sort some data from the database. The sorting works fine if I removed the #pack from the href in the a tags, but it returns to the top of the page. I need it to reach the section of the page with the id pack.
This is the HTML portion

```
    <h1 id="pack">Packages</h1>
    <div class="sort">
    <p>Sort By <a href="index.php#pack?sort=htl"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-desc" aria-hidden="true"></i> Price high to low</a> | <a href="index.php#pack?sort=lth"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc" aria-hidden="true"></i> Price low to high</a></p>
    </div>
```

I need it to return to the id "pack".
This is the php code I used.

```
        if(isset($_GET['sort']))
        {
            $sort=$_GET['sort'];
            if($sort=='htl')
            {
                $package_details=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM package_details ORDER BY cost DESC"); 
            }
            if($sort=='lth')
            {
                $package_details=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM package_details ORDER BY cost"); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $package_details=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM package_details");  
        }
```

UPDATE
It is working after removing the smooth scrolling js. How can I do it without removing it. Here's the code.

```html
//   Adding Smooth Scroll with JQuery.......................................................

// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
    // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
    .not('[href="#"]')
    .not('[href="#0"]')
    .click(function (event) {
        // On-page links
        if (
            location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') &&
            location.hostname == this.hostname
        ) {
            // Figure out element to scroll to
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            // Does a scroll target exist?
            if (target.length) {
                // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000, function () {
                    // Callback after animation
                    // Must change focus!
                    var $target = $(target);
                    $target.focus();
                    if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        $target.attr('tabindex', '-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
                        $target.focus(); // Set focus again
                    };
                });
            }
        }
    });

//
```

Comment: ? should come before the #, like <a href="index.php?sort=htl#pack">

Answer (score 0):

By removing the hash, if it works for you, then I guess, it should work by

`<a href="index.php?sort=htl#pack">`

moving the hash to end of the URL, by the way, you can also reach the section of the page, like

```
<h1 id="pack">Packages</h1>
    <div class="sort">
    <p>Sort By <a href="index.php?sort=htl#pack"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-desc" aria-hidden="true"></i> Price high to low</a> | <a href="index.php#pack?sort=lth"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc" aria-hidden="true"></i> Price low to high</a></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: It is working, but only after removing the smooth scrolling js.